# ngrx store is suddenly not loading a State property and its reducer ( Angular Cli)

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, ngrx

After some trivial application changes, my ngrx store is suddenly not loading properly. As you can see in the screen shot below, I am getting most of my store properties and those are even loading my api results through their reducers, but I'm missing 1 critical state property `uiState`.

I've undone my trivial changes and restarted my browser, terminal, cleared my cache and local storage and restarted my computer, but my `uiState` is not getting added to my store and its reducer is never called. Could this be and Angular Cli or Webpack memory issue? If so how can I clear the memory?

[image]

this is what my state should look like:

```
export interface AppState {
  uiState: UIState;
  foodStaging: $DietEntryMap;
  recipeBuilder: RecipeBuilder;
  dbData: MongoData;
}
```

and Here is how I compose my reducers:

```
const reducers = {
  uiState: uiStateReducer,
  recipeBuilder: recipeReducer,
  foodStaging: stagingReducer,
  dbData: dbDataReducer
};

const developmentReducer: ActionReducer<AppState> =
  compose(
    storeFreeze,
    storeLogger(loggerOptions),
    localStorageSync(['dbData'], true),
    combineReducers)
  (reducers);

const productionReducer: ActionReducer<AppState> =
  compose(localStorageSync(['dbData']), combineReducers)(reducers);

export function storeReducer(state: AppState, action: any) {
  if (environment.production) return productionReducer(state, action);
  else return developmentReducer(state, action);
}
```

And my UiState reducer looks like this:

```
export function uiStateReducer(state: UIState = INITIAL_UI_STATE, action: UiActions): UIState {
  switch (action.type) {
    // action handlers
  }
}
```

`INITIAL_UI_STATE` is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some issue when I tried to import a helper function, from a reducer file, through a barrel, into an Effect service. I just moved the whole function over to the effect and everything worked.